# Create Contact with Google People API + PHP (Server to Server)

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to create a new contact through google people api + PHP (Server-to-server) using the code below and the code apparently runs without errors, but no contacts are created at: https://www.google.com/contacts/

Querying the contacts as described here (https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) I see that the contact was created.

I use Google App Suite.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('my configs...');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS);
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();

$email = new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress();
$email->setValue('test@test.com');
$person->setEmailAddresses($email);

$name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
$name->setDisplayName('User de Test');
$person->setNames($name);

$exe = $service->people->createContact($person);

print_r($exe);
```

Comment: `Is there anything wrong with my code?` You tell us. Is the script working? any errors? what's wrong with it?

Comment: You would first need to create an OAUTH Session with google on-behalf of your app to create contacts on your account. If you're using a service account ( two-legged-oauth ) then adding the contact without first creating a session, it's probably being saved under the service-accounts scope

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try this php library it did the same task for me 
https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api

Installation :-

-download the repo `git clone https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api`

-then run `composer require rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api`

-create api credential on google api here https://console.developers.google.com/

-then rename the `.config_blank.json` to `.config.json` and update the `clientID`,`clientSecret` to the credential you get from the api console

-update the `redirectUri` in the .config.json file to the full path to your `redirect-handler.php` file

-then go ahead and open `authorise-application.php` in your browser & open the provided link in a new tab to authorize your app then this page will redirect you to the file `redirect-handler.php` and will ask you to add the hash providedd to the `.config.json` file for the attribute `refreshToken`

-done you can try this code to create new contact in your account

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$contact->name = 'Test';
$contact->phoneNumber = '07812363789';
$contact->email = 'test@example.com';
$contact->content = 'Note for example';

$contactAfterUpdate =rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory::submitUpdates($contact);

var_dump($contactAfterUpdate);
```

Update:
as [DivineOmega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160723/divineomega)'s comment
there is a new version of the API [Here](https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api)  you can try it.

Comment: Please consider to also explain how to use the library, and how this solves the problem in your answer above, when linking to external resources.

Comment: Thanks for mentioned our Google Contacts library. We've actually created a new library that uses the Google People API. It might be worth updating your answer to include it. https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api